# Azure Custom Script extension tasks not running in background

Tags: powershell, azure

I am using Azure Custom script extensions to automate deployment of Azure VM's. In one case I am installing XAMPP and configuring various services however after installing everything the apache process is no longer running. if I log into the machine and manually start the process it runs just fine.

here is the script i am using to start the powershell script that installs and configures XAMPP

```
$password =  ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$env:COMPUTERNAME\username", $password)
$command = $file = $PSScriptRoot + "\WebServerSetup.ps1"
Enable-PSRemoting –force
Invoke-Command -FilePath $command -Credential $credential -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
Disable-PSRemoting -Force
```

the script to setup the webserver is rather long but here is where i start the Apache service

```
Start-Process c:\xampp\apache_stop.bat  

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

Start-Job c:\xampp\apache_start.bat
```

After running the automation scripts all configuration is complete but the process is not running... if I manually run the command it works just fine. I assumed the issue was because the bat file wanted to run in its own window so i tried "xampp_start.exe" which doesnt open a new window and the result was the same.

Comment: is there a specific reason you are using start-job instead of start-process?

Comment: I read that it would run the process in the background so I gave it a shot. I also tried Start-Process with various parameters such  as -Wait and -NoWindow but neither worked ... well let me rephrase .. all started the process but once the script was finished the Apache program stopped

Comment: have you checked the apache logfile for an error? Also try to start it with credentials supplied

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `Invoke-Command` automatically closes all processes that were started from its session after the Command is executed.

So the easy solution should be:

Dont use `Invoke-Command` to start your powershell script.

If you have to supply Credentials try the following:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "$command" -Credential $credential
```

otherwise just run the script:

```
$command
```